# auth.currentUser is null after sometimes in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, next-auth

I am using firebase authentication with NextAuth in my trpc server. Everything is fine but when user is loggedin for a sometimes and user tries to update their password. It shows an error because currentUser is null.

```
const app = initializeApp(GoogleConfig)
const auth = getAuth(app)
const user = auth?.currentUser

const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credntial(req.input.email, req.input.currentPassword)
await reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential).catch(err => console.log("Error", err))
await updatePassword(user!, req.input.newPassword).catch(err => console.log("err:", err))

return {
  message: "Password changed"
}
```

I am trying to first reauthenticate the user using reauthenticateWithCredential and using updatePassword() updating the password. Becaue sometimes currentUser of auth becomes null, user sometimes are not able to change their password. Can anyone give me an idea why it is happeningand how to get rid of this?

I have tried `onAuthStateChanged` but I think I should use it for Frontend. It did not work.

Comment: [Why is my currentUser == null in Firebase Auth?](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/why-is-my-currentuser-null-in-firebase-auth-4701791f74f0)

Comment: Hey Doug, Thanks for the link. I have already checked that out, and followed this but did not solve my problem. The problem I am facing is it works almost 90% time but sometimes after a day or 12 hours, it does not work.

Comment: Please edit your question to include exact instructions to reliably reproduce the issue.  Right now you have "sometimes" there is a problem, but we need to know what the specific conditions are.  You might be doing something wrong.

Comment: thanks you  @DougStevenson  that   really  make essay to undeartand

Comment: Hey. The thing is when user tries to update their password, it works perfectly but after for example 12 hours when they try to update, the currentUser becomes null. I tried what @Parthis suggested on the other answer. But it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can then use that user object to reauthenticate and update the password. Like  this

```
const app = initializeApp(GoogleConfig)
const auth = getAuth(app)

auth.onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
if (user) {
// User is signed in, so perform the password update
const credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(req.input.email, 
req.input.currentPassword)
await reauthenticateWithCredential(user, credential)
await updatePassword(user, req.input.newPassword)
return {
  message: "Password changed"
}
} else {
// User is not signed in, so prompt them to log in
// You can redirect the user to a login page or display a login 
form here
 console.log("User is not signed in")
 }
})
```

Comment: Hey Parthis. Thanks for your comment. I have tried this before, but it did not work. Now, I tried again, Unfortunately, it does not work. It still returns currentUser as null!

Comment: can you  share more details ?

Comment: i think if you appliyed   if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    // Save the user's uid or other identifying information.
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // Clear any saved user information.
  } on auth.onAuthStateChanged((user)  and  i  try to make  example for you

Comment: Hey. An example would be really great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: good  if  that help  can  you  do up  vote?